# Lubuntu usb only booting on one computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, lubuntu, usb-drive

So this is officially my first time trying to make a bootable version of Lubuntu on a flash drive, so it is entirely possible I messed up somewhere.

After a few attempts I was able to install Lubuntu 16.10 on a 16GB flashdrive. I separate the space into a 12GB space for the software and the rest i set up as a swap area.

The laptop I used for the install will boot up the OS just fine(Albeit everything runs really slowly..I'll figure that out later) but if I try to boot on my PC It won't load up. I tried opening BIOS and selecting the usb to boot from. What happens is the screen goes black then "Boot failure press any key to continue" pops up. Pressing any key just results in the message reappearing on the next line.

When I Tried changing the boot order in BIOS(to see if that did anything) it will just skip over my usb(sort of expected it) and load my normal OS on that machine (Windows 10 fyi)

I'm pretty sure I missed something during the install of Lubuntu but it also might be something I didn't configure in my Desktop's BIOS.

Sorry if this is a duplicate issue I skimmed the"Questions that may have your answer" and didn't see a title that quite fit

Answer (score 0):

try the step by step from this link to see if it helps.

[How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

From your description, looks like you do not have the GRUB set up for boot, or you have another kind of boot (UEFI) set for your Windows 10, that´s maybe the cause you can´t boot your USB.
But if you change the UEFI boot configuration in BIOS, you might not boot Windows until change it all back later.

Regards